# Request for one particular image ends in 502 bad gateway and proxy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, mongrel, redmine

I have the Ruby on Rails-based application Redmine (based on the BitNami redmine package) running on a Windows virtual server. It runs Apache, Mongrel, Ruby, and rails.

When, in a HTML page I am building a template for, I request a static image resource named `/templates/mytemplate/images/bkg.jpg` - around 15 kilobytes big - I get a `502 Bad gateway` error about two out of three requests. x

[image]
<sub>(source: [pekkagaiser.com](http://pekkagaiser.com/blog/user/files/502.jpg))</sub>

Apache's error log then contains

```
on Apr 12 22:50:33 2010] [error] (620018)APR does not understand this error code:
proxy: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:3001 (127.0.0.1)

[Mon Apr 12 22:50:33 2010] [error] proxy: pass request body failed to 127.0.0.1:3001
(127.0.0.1) from 78.34.240.113 ()
```

It's only for that one resource. Other, much larger images and CSS style sheets get loaded every time without problems.

Oddly, this will happen only if the image is used as a background image in a CSS style sheet. Repeated direct access tol the image in the browser works fine, even with the cache turned off. Could this be a referer problem? But I can't see how.

I know very little about Ruby nor Rails. Can anybody tell me what this could be and where I should look?

Update: On second thought, this might belong on serverfault. Migrate away if you think the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Rails and that sorted it out.